# How do I figure out what user & group Apache is running as?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, permissions, dreamhost, .htpasswd

On DreamHost shared hosting, I'm setting up htpasswd, but Apache does not have permission to read the file. How do I give it permission? I want to either change the owner or group of the `.htpasswd` file instead of giving it insecure permissions. I don't think I have access to the `httpd.conf` file, so I can't use this method to [find what user Apache runs as](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=263064). Also, running `top` or `ps aux` only shows the processes I'm running but doesn't show the apache process.

Based on the output from `cat /etc/passwd` and `cat /etc/group`, I'm guessing it's `www-data`.

Well, I followed the instructions for [Password-protecting directories on Dreamhost](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Password-protecting_directories). It generated a directory with a `.htpasswd` file with the group `dhapache` and permissions `440`. It also put a `.htaccess` file in there with under my group. For some reason, when I try `chgrp dhapache test_file.txt` I get `chgrp: changing group of 'test_file.txt': Operation not permitted`. So, I just moved the `.htpasswd` file that DreamHost generated to where I wanted it and edited the `.htaccess` file it generated, despite its warnings.

Comment: yes, typically it's "www-data:www-data"

Answer (score 10):

Actually, you don't need access to httpd.conf:

```
ps aux | grep apache2
groups apache_user
```

should yield what You want

Comment: Or better `ps axo user,group,comm | grep apache`

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't work on DreamHost, but I figured it out. See the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: It is a bit strange that `ps aux` didn't work for You (since dreamhost itself declares it should http://wiki.dreamhost.com/PS_Optimization); however, glad You did it one way or another.

Comment: ps aux does not always display group information ... use ps axo above.

Answer (score 4):

I was having some issue that leads me to another solution. But it only works when you have access to the configuration file

We can actually check the user and group in `\etc\apache2\envars` file. This is where Apache set the environments var and use it across application.

Look for this two lines:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

Note this is just setting environment variables. The actual setting the apache to run as what user/group is actually in the `\etc\apache2\apache2.conf`

```
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

The location of the files might me different but you should get the idea.