# You don't have permission error in Apache in CentOS

Tags: linux, apache, centos, chmod, document-root

I have installed apache 2.2 in centos 6. Everything worked fine when the apache folder was at its default location `/var/www/html`. Then I configured a Virtual host inside my users home folder. After that apache started showing `Forbidden You don't have permission error` when I tried to go to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` from browser.

this is the code i used in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/home/anjan/workspace/mfs"
        ServerName anjan-centOS
        <Directory "/home/anjan/workspace/mfs">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also disabled `SElinux` as was mentioned in some articles but in vain. If anyone could help me out it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a basic permissions problem, not an Apache problem.  What user is Apache running as?  Does that user have access to `/home/anjan/workspace/mfs`?

Comment: A good way to check if apache can read the directory is to `sudo -u apache ls /home/anjan/worskapce/mfs`

Comment: @CoreyHenderson I have changed file permission of every file & folder to `-rw-rw-rw-` but still no luck. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem. After meddling with the permission of the system I found out that the `user "anjan"` who is owner of `/home/anjan` had read/write/execute permission on `/home/anjan` but the `group "anjan"`, created when `user "anjan"` was created didn't have any permission at all.

```
ls -l /home/
```

showed

```
drwx------. 28 anjan anjan 4096 Jan 21 13:19 anjan
```

so I changed the permission with this command

```
chmod -R 770 /home/anjan
ls -l /home/
drwxrwx---. 28 anjan anjan 4096 Jan 21 13:19 anjan
```

i found out under which user my apache is running from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509334/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as) thread. It was running under `user "apache"`

so I added `user "apache"` to `group "anjan"` with this command.

```
usermod -G anjan,apache apache
```

after that voila. No more **Forbidden** error.

P.S. I did everything as the root user.

**UPDATE**
It seems the provided link is broken now. [Heres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4317156/1682148) another one.

Just to be safe(to avoid future broken links), copying the command here. In terminal type -

```
ps axo user,group,comm | grep apache
```

Comment: Totally worked for RHEL!  This was the missing link.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

This is (for me at least) a doubtful design. It basically means that the Apache user has WRITE access to all that user's files including secrets for example ssh-keys.

Not fun if a cracker attacks apache.

A simple modification would be while running as 'anjan':

```
chmod -R g-rwx ~ # undo the unsafe -R first
chmod g+rx ~ ~/workspace
chmod -R g+rx ~/workspace/mfs
```

If `apache` is a member of the 'anjan' group.

My recommendation is to use ACL:s if the filesystem supports that.

Is SELinux running now ? It should be so and if is still the case that the SELinux policy blocks apache's access to `workspace/mfs` a number of messages from sealert should be evident in var/log/messages.
This problem is usually fixed with a judicious usage of setsebol.

Disabling SELinux because something isn't working and recommending that method is njaa....

The original problem is that apache runs as itself and because of that is slumped in the other category when calculating permissions.

```
chmod o+rx ~anjan/ ~anjan/workspace/ ~anjan/workspace/mfs
```

should be enough.

CentOS 6  is a free (as in free beer) version of RedHat Enterprise Linux and as such RedHat's document https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/ is a necessity.

Comment: You have made a valid point. But in my case I was setting up a dev environment that's why I placed the codes inside users home directory. But for production I think it's also not a good idea to place codes in any users home directory.