# Apache user 403 forbidden all sites offline

Tags: apache, http

I have used the following command in centos to set permissions but something went terrible wrong!

usermod -G myusergroup,apache apache

Now all my sites are giving me the 403 forbidden page!
How can i reset this?

Comment: Used this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427808/you-dont-have-permission-error-in-apache-in-centos please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

When you use usermod -G you specify the groups the user belongs to. If you does not include the current groups in the command the user will get removed from these groups.

For example:
User: A, Group: 1, 2, 3

Usermod -G 1,3 A
This will remove user A from group 2.

So be carefull with this command.

I have added the user Apache to the group Access and Apache and now my websites are working again.

Merl.