# apache2 running root despite defined to www-data in envvars

Tags: apache

My server seems to run apache2 as root despite set to www-data in /etc/apache2/envvars.

How can this happen ?

- /etc/apache2/envvars

  export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
  export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
- Here is how I checked it

[How do I figure out what user & group Apache is running as?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317156/how-do-i-figure-out-what-user-group-apache-is-running-as)

```
ps axo user,group,comm | grep apache
root     root     apache2
root     root     apache2
root     root     apache2
root     root     apache2
root     root     apache2
root     root     apache2
root     root     apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that APACHE_RUN_USER is supposed to be the user that apache2 uses to read, write, or execute the files in your website. Not the user that runs the apache2 server. You wouldn't want your server running webpages as root, because files you may want to keep the user from accessing will become visible. I may be wrong though. Try running service apache2 restart, and checking again.